# libcurl FTP-Download incomplete in the Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, unreal-engine4

I am currently trying to download a File from a public git-Repository using curl in my Unreal C++ Project. Here is the code I'm trying to execute that I derived from the [FTP-Example](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/ftpget.html):

```
// This is in the .h file
struct FFtpFile {
    FILE* File;
    const char* Filename;
};

void FtpFetch(const std::string URL, const char* Filename) {
    CURL* Curl = curl_easy_init();

    const FFtpFile FtpFile {
        nullptr,
        Filename
    };
    
    if (!Curl) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Error Initiating cURL"));
        return;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
    // Data Callback
    const auto WriteCallback = +[](void* Contents, const size_t Size, const size_t NumMem, FFtpFile* FileStruct) -> size_t {
        if (!FileStruct->File) {
            fopen_s(&FileStruct->File, FileStruct->Filename, "wb");
            if (!FileStruct->File) {
                return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR;
            }
        }
        return fwrite(Contents, Size, NumMem, FileStruct->File);
    };
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, DownloadCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(Curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, FtpFile);

    
    const CURLcode Result = curl_easy_perform(Curl);
    if (Result != CURLE_OK) {
        const FString Message(curl_easy_strerror(Result));
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Error Getting Content of the Model File: %s"), *Message);
        return;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(Curl);

    // Close the Stream after Cleanup
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Successfully Fetched FTP-File. Closing Write Stream"))
    if (FtpFile.File) {
        fclose(FtpFile.File);
    }
}
```

Note that this is executed on a separate Thread using the Unreal Async function:

```
void AsyncFetchModelFile(const std::string URL) {
    std::string Path = ...
    
    TFunction<void()> Task = [Path, URL]() {
        FtpFetch(URL, Path.c_str());
    };

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Fetching FTP on Background Thread"))
    Async(EAsyncExecution::Thread, Task, [](){UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Finishied FTP on Background Thread!"))});
}
```

I already removed the curl_global calls, as the documentation states those are not thread-safe. I also tried running the code on the main thread, but the same error happens there too.

To the error itself: The download runs almost flawlessly, but the downloaded file (in this case a .fbx file) always misses the last ~800 Bytes and is therefore incomplete. Also, the file keeps being open in Unreal, so I can't delete/move the file unless I close the Editor.

Before writing this Unreal code I tried running the same code in a pure C++ setting and there it worked flawlessly. But for some reason doing the same in Unreal doesn't work.

I also tried using a private method instead of the lambda-Function, but that didn't make any difference.

Any help would be appreciated
~Okaghana

Comment: It sounds as if you may have the last ~800 bytes in a buffer. Why is `FtpFile` `const`? Show the `DownloadCallback` function too please.

Comment: Btw, are you calling `curl_global_init` at program start and `curl_global_cleanup` at program end?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The `curl_global_init` [documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html) states: `This function is not thread-safe. You must not call it when any other thread in the program is running` so I removed it from the code as this code is running on a different thread. But putting it in doesn't fix the problem.

FtpFile is const because Rider recommended me to do it. But it also doesn't seem to make a difference.

I agree that It feels like the last batch of data is not correctly written to file, but the question is: why is that?

Comment: The [`curl_easy_init`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html) documentation also states "_If you did not already call `curl_global_init`, `curl_easy_init` does it automatically. This may be lethal in multi-threaded cases, since `curl_global_init` is not thread-safe, and it may result in resource problems because there is no corresponding cleanup._" - So, I recommend that you call it _once_ at program startup (and then call `curl_global_cleanup ` once at program exit).

Comment: (unless you are putting it in a DLL - don't put it in `DllMain` or a static initializer in that case)

Comment: Since I'm using trying it in a whole game calling it at the very beginning and end is somewhat difficult, but I tried to call it as early and late as I could as well as right before and after I use curl. Both didn't have an effect on the problem.

Comment: No, it may not have a visible effect now on the problem you're struggling with now but it may affect the stability of your program. What I personally do is to wrap `curl_easy` up in a class which has a `static` member variable, which, when instantiated, calls `curl_global_init` and `curl_global_cleanup` in the destructor. That way, the first `curl_easy` object that is created will call `curl_global_init` in a thread safe manner.

Comment: I started making a little C++ wrapper a few years back. It can only do the most basic stuff, but you can look at how `curl_global_init` is done if you'd like: [curl::Easy++](https://github.com/TedLyngmo/curl-Easy-cpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to get it working in the end (I suspect it's an Unreal-Related Bug), but I found another way using the included Unreal HTTP Module:

```
FString Path = ...

// Create the Callback when the HTTP-Request has finished
auto OnRequestComplete = [Path](FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful) {
    if (bWasSuccessful) {
        FFileHelper::SaveArrayToFile(Response->GetContent(), *Path);
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Successfully downloaded the file to '%s'"), *Path)
    } else {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Error downloading the file (See EHttpResponseCodes): %s"), Response->GetResponseCode())
    }
};


// Create a HTTP-Request and Fetch the file
TSharedRef<IHttpRequest, ESPMode::ThreadSafe> Request = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest();
Request->SetVerb("GET");
Request->SetURL(URL);
Request->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindLambda(OnRequestComplete);

Request->ProcessRequest();
```